# Using array_rand to select a top level array and all it's decendents

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi there I'm a bit confused on how I go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following code.

```
$worms_level1 = $this->catch_the_worm_model->get_worms_by_level(1);
$captured_worms = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_worms; $i++)
{
    $captured_worms[$i] = array_rand($worms_level1);
}

return $captured_worms;
```

The $worms_level1 multidimensional array takes the following format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [worm_id] => 1 
                       [worm_name] => Verm 
                       [worm_description] => The most common verm, not a huge threat but a great nuisance. 
                       [worm_level] => 1 
                       [worm_value] => 1 ) 

        [1] => Array ( [worm_id] => 2 
                       [worm_name] => Vermichav 
                       [worm_description] => Vermichav loves a scuffle. He's been known to spit in Wormcatcher's eyes and inflict pain by cigarette burns. 
                       [worm_level] => 1 [worm_value] => 1 )
     )
```

At the minute the code is successful at selecting random arrays and saving them to a new array eg

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 )
```

but I also want the descendent arrays to be saved to the new array.

Comment: you might find this easier if `$worms_level1` were an SplObjectStorage object containing Worm objects.

Comment: Thanks for tidying that up and replying ;) I'm quite inexperienced when it comes to PHP so SplObjectStorage objects aren't something I'm familiar with. I'll have a look into it now. Surely there must be something I can do with the arrays as they are now?

Comment: you can definitely work with the array as it is now. It's just a bit awkward.  In any event, whether you decide to use `SplObjectStorage` or not, a `Worm` object will make life easier by changing your multidimensional array into a vanilla array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$captured_worms=array();
$howmany=20;
do{
    $howmany-=count($captured_worms);//decreases $howmany by the number we already grabbed
    shuffle($multiarray); //reorder the multiarray randomly
    $captured_worms=array_slice($multiarray,0,$howmany);//get as many elements as you want
} while(count($captured_worms)<$howmany); //ensures at least $howmany
```

Comment: Thanks, what would happen if the $multiarray has less elements than I need? Ideally I would want it to return duplicates

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help, it took me a while to get my head around this, but I've got it working now :)